# Is SX lock in MySQL the same as a update lock

Tags: mysql

According to [All about locking in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/), a update lock can be transformed into a exclusive lock when there is something to write. Meanwhile, the compatibility of the three locks(X,S and U) can be refer to the following table.

```
    X   S   U
X   ✗   ✗   ✗
S   ✗   ✓   ✓
U   ✗   ✓   ✗
```

However, It is mentioned in some blogs that there is a SX lock since MySQL 5.7 which implements an idea from the paper *Concurrency of operations on B-trees(1977)*. From these blogs I find the SX lock is quite similar with the update lock. For example, they have the same compatibility table.

Since I can't find more "official" introduction about the SX lock in MySQL, I want to ask what's the difference between both of the locks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the compatibility matrix defines a lock, having the same matrix makes the update lock and the sx lock equivalent.

Actually, in database theory, an update lock should behave asymmetrical, disallowing a new shared lock when there is already an update lock, see e.g. [these lecture notes](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/nyu/02fa/notes/l8.pdf), penultimate page. Your reference also mentions this:

> It is important to understand that update lock is asymmetrical in regards of shared locks. While the update lock can be imposed on a record that has the shared lock, the shared lock cannot be imposed on the record that already has the update lock

Practically though, both the MySQL sx-lock and the SQL Server (and others) update lock are symmetrical, like in your matrix.

The purpose of an update lock is to allow other transactions to still read the data (using a shared lock) while preventing a deadlock when two transactions want to escalate to a exclusive lock (as neither can do that when the other has a shared lock).

So, to conclude, the lock types are, in principle, the same, although I could imagine that they are named differently to emphasize that they are not intended to be asymmetric, and maybe to leave an option to later add the "real" update lock, so you may or may not want to treat them as unequal in that regard.

But there are major differences in how they are used. For example, in contrast to SQL Server, MySQL does not use update locks on rows: MySQL uses exclusive locks for updates, and to allow for concurrent reads, usually does not lock while reading, unless you use [locking reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

After acid requirements, the detailled behaviour (when which lock is applied on what object for what operation) is mostly relevant for performance and concurrency. While you could just lock the whole database for every query, this would only allow one query at a time, so the more fine-grained you lock specific objects, the more concurrency you allow (with the tradeoff to increase the risk of deadlocks).

Now to the purpose of the sx-locks in MySQL:

They were introduced to allow a more fine-tuned locking of indexes, see [MySQL-5.7 improves DML oriented workloads](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-improves-dml-oriented-workloads/), as some operations on indexes required the complete index to be exclusively locked, hindering concurrency. So the reason they are not more present int the documentation is that, although there might be other use cases for this type in the future, they are currently limited to very specific internal locking.